# Precisely moving, rotating and scaling the mesh in the Sculpt mode do not work properly. Is this a Bug?

Tags: transforms, sculpting, brushes, sculpt-mode

Here is the default cube with some loop cuts:

[image]

Now, in the Sculpt mode, let's mask the upper half of the cube, and then use the scale brush to increase the scale of the lower half in the X and Z direction by 14%, respectively. (The scale in the Y direction should remain unchanged.)

[image]

Obviously, the result looks wrong in the Z direction. The actual scale in the Z direction does not increase, but, instead, it decreases. This limits my ability to precisely scale the mesh in the Sculpt mode.

The trouble also happens when use the move brush and rotate brush, because the input values do not match the final result. Is this a bug please? I have test it in 2.90, 2.93 and 3.0 Beta. All have the same problem.
Thank you!

You can download and test the original file from here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/o4w9445fmwu2ihx/testing%20scale%20brush.blend?dl=0

Comment: Yeah I think this is a bug. Unless I'm mistaken on how it should work, the scale tool in sculpt mode is bugged.

Comment: Not only the precise value of the scaling can not be controlled, but also I find that the direction of the scaling is also buggy and hard to control, when scale a mesh with a more complicated shape and with a mask.  Moreover, move and rotate brushes are suffering from the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Before enter to "Sculpt Mode" verify that the scale has been applied, if not this may be the cause.
In "Object Mode" do Ctr+A then Scale, or in the toolbar Object-Apply-Scale
[image]