# Sculpt Mode transform tool acting up (BLENDER 3.0)

Tags: transforms, sculpting

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

so I am trying to transform (scale and rotate) the unmasked area but whenever I try to move those manipulators already the unmasked area goes out of proportion. It's like it has a mind of it's
own, see the second screenshot to see what happened to the unmasked area.

Comment: Hello, it's not clear what the problem, could you please elaborate, maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Please look at the answer in this post. hope it helps https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/243370/precisely-moving-rotating-and-scaling-the-mesh-in-the-sculpt-mode-do-not-work-p/278268#278268